# Delete files from File System of IOS SIMULATOR

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to delete images from image folder in library folder of an App created when accessing the app in simulator.The file has to be deleted through coding ie when the app has started running.

folder present in IOS simulator's file system?

Answer (score 2):

The simulator installs apps are here.

```
/Users/<system username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

GUID files and directories install on your simulator.
or you can uninstall app by Long Left button pressing and the cross.
Try this and let me know for any query.

Answer (score 2):

The files that are saved in the library folder are present in the path

/Users/YourSystemName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0 or 5.0 or etc/Applications

You can delete files of particular application from this folder.

But you can simply **reset content and settings** of iphone simulator to reset. This can done by

1. Selecting ios simulator.
2. Go to top menu and select iphone simulator.
3. Select option reset contents and settings and then reset.

Comment: Well thanks I understood now how manually to  delete these files.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you then please accept the answer so that it will also help to others. Thanks :)